# class pointer unitialized local variable

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Recently in my c++ class we have learned about pointers and classes.

I'm trying  to make a program that has a `class Student`, which we will point to give each student a name and test score.

After entering both name and test score, they are sorted and then listed in order of highest to lowest.

I believe all my syntax to be correct, however I am still learning. The problem I am having is that the first time I use my class I get an uninitialized local variable error, any help on how to fix this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    double score;
    string name;
public:
    void setScore(double a) {
        score = a;
    }
    double getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    void setName(string b) {
        name = b;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
};

void sorting(Student*, int);

int main()
{
    Student *students;
    string name;
    int score;
    int *count;
    count = new int;
    cout << "How many students? ";
    cin >> *count;
    while (*count <= 0) {
        cout << "ERROR: The number of students must be greater than 0.\n";
        cin >> *count;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < *count; i++) {
        cout << "Please enter the students name: ";
        cin >> name;
        students[i].setName(name);
        cout << "Please enter " << students[i].getName() << "'s score: ";
        cin >> score;
        while (score < 0) {
            cout << "ERROR: Score must be a positive number.\n";
            cin >> score;
        }
        students[i].setScore(score);
    }
    sorting(students, *count);
    for (int i = 0; i < *count; i++) {
        cout << students[i].getName() << ": " << students[i].getScore() << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void sorting(Student *s, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < size; j++) {
            if (s[j].getScore() > s[(j + 1)].getScore()) {
                int tmp = s[(j + 1)].getScore();
                s[(j + 1)].setScore(s[j].getScore());
                s[j].setScore(tmp);
                string tmp1 = s[(j + 1)].getName();
                s[(j + 1)].setName(s[j].getName());
                s[j].setName(tmp1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `students` is a pointer to `Student`. Make it an array once you know the `count` using `students = new Student[count];`.

Comment: There's no need to do `count = new int;` Just declare it as `int count`;

Comment: `count = new int;`  -- You or your teacher has gone overboard with the pointer requirements if you write code like this.  Also, they didn't teach `delete`?

Comment: So many `new`s, so little `delete`s...

Comment: Side note: you can assign `Student`s to each other; `Student tmp = s[j+1];` is nicer than mucking around with getters and setters.

Comment: @molbdnilo Or if you just want to swap the two you could use... the `std::swap` function.

Comment: Don't use `students = new Student[count]`; use `vector<Student> students; /* ... */ students.resize(count);`. If your teacher disagrees, ask them to explain why they think beginning programmers should be worrying about manual memory management, and inviting memory leaks by not `delete`ing, when the stdlib makes this unnecessary in almost all situations. The answer is bound to be entertaining and/or horrifying.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your `Student` class can be simplified to this:

```
struct Student {
    double score;
    std::string name;
};
```

Because the accessors do absolutely nothing. I've also added the `std::` prefix because [`using namespace std` is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice).

Now, instead of using the pointer to store the students, include `vector` and use that:

```
std::cout << "How many students? ";
int count;
std::cin >> count;

std::vector<Student> students(count);
```

The loading routine can also be simplified given the absence of accesors:

```
for (auto& student : students) {
    std::cout << "Please enter the students name: ";
    std::cin >> student.name;
    std::cout << "Please enter " << student.name << "'s score: ";
    std::cin >> student.score;
    while (score < 0) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Score must be a positive number.\n";
        std::cin >> student.score;
    }
}
```

And actually once you have that, you could just put it in `istream& operator>>(istream&, Student&)` and reduce it to:

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<Student>(std::cin), students.size(), students.begin());
```

No need now for temporary variables anymore (and even if you want to use them, they should be defined *just before the use*, so inside of the loop).

The last thing is your sorting routine. First off, there's `std::sort` that you can use instead if you simply provide a comparator:

```
std::sort(
    begin(students),
    end(students),
    [](Student const& a, Student const& b) { return b.score < a.score; }
);
```

If you insist on writing the sorting routine yourself, at least use `std::swap`.